# akka scheduler delay not working

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I'm trying to use akka in play-java 2.4. ,my code is the next.

```
Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
            Duration.create(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
            () -> System.out.println("hello on " + new Date()),
            Akka.system().dispatcher()
    );
```

according to the documentation, the first param of schedule method is initial delay. But it has no effect at all, code is running rigth after start and then every minute, as it was passed as a parameter. Where is the mistake in this code?

Comment: The code seems right to me. Make sure there are no other tasks scheduled that may be confusing you. Also can you create a minimal/simple project online that shows this problem?